# Some html tags' parameters messup html/php code

Tags: php, html

When I create/edit post to my website, and when I use html tags (either type it by my self or using WYSIWYG editor (in this case nicEdit, but I've used different one - same problem)) it does not show anything on the page.

to be more specific: I have `article` container which imports php code, which than iterates through the db table and `echo` posts. This is the code:

```
<h3>Wydarzenia</h3>
<?php
    //collects data from table "events" and sort it by "id" date in descending oreder
    $event_table_data = mysqli_query($db_con, "SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY id DESC") 
        or die(mysqli_error());

    //puts the data from "events" into an array
    $event_content_array = mysqli_fetch_array($event_table_data); 

    //makes variables from table columns
    $id = id;
    $title = title;
    $happeninng_date = happen;
    $created_date = created;
    $content = content;
    $author = author;

    //add new post button
    if((isset($_SESSION['sess_wizardrights'])) && ($_SESSION['sess_wizardrights'] == true)){
        echo    "<a class='e_event_addpost_link' href='./index.php?link=add_post'><button  class='e_event_addpost_button' type='button'>Dodaj nowy post</button></a>";
    }

    do{
        //echo each event for main event article
        echo    "<span class='b_events_span' id='" . $event_content_array[$id] . "'>";
        echo    "   <a class='b_events_anchor' id='" . $event_content_array[$id] . "'></a>";
        echo    "   <h2 class='b_events_title'>" . $event_content_array[$title] . "</h2>";
        if((isset($_SESSION['sess_wizardrights'])) && ($_SESSION['sess_wizardrights'] == true)){
            echo    "<form class='b_events_edit_form' name='edit_post' action='./index.php?link=edit_post' method='post'>";
            echo    "   <input type='hidden' name='id' value='" . $event_content_array[$id] . "'> ";
            echo    "   <input class='e_events_edit_submit' type='submit' value='Edytuj wydarzenie'>";
            echo    "</form>";
        }
        echo    "   <div class='fb-share-button' data-href='http://www.zhppgkaberdeen.co.uk/index.php?link=events#" . $event_content_array[$id] . "'></div>";
        echo    "   <p class='b_events_happening_date'><i>Data wydarzenia: " . $event_content_array[$happeninng_date] . "</i></p>";
        echo    "   <p class='b_events_content'>" . $event_content_array[$content] . "</p>";
        echo    "   <p class='b_events_created_date'>Utworzono: " . $event_content_array[$created_date] . "</p>";
        echo    "   <p class='b_events_author'><b>Czuwaj!</b><br/>" . $event_content_array[$author] . "</p>";
        echo    "</span>";

    }while($event_content_array = mysqli_fetch_array( $event_table_data ));
?>
```

When I add tags like `<img>` for instance with `alt=""` parameter it completely ruins web page. What I mean by that is that the `article` container is not shown at all (I've checked that with firebug) as well as everything after the `article` tag (like footer for instance). What is even more strange is that this: `alt="text"` did not break the page but every other random word does, how ever it does not show the "text" at image at all.

Similar thing happen when I tried to create table within the post and title or target parameter, I cant remember which one.

I have tried to use `htmlentities($event_content_array[$content])`, `htmlspecialchar($event_content_array[$content])` and `mysqli_real_escape_string($do_con, $event_content_array[$content])` -> non of this helped.

Is there a way to fix that or I just need to give up using this tags/parameters?

Thank you for any help or explanation

Comment: Firebug etc cleans up the output. Use view source in your browser. You should look into escaping and the proper use of " and '.

Comment: I found out that I have a similar panel before the main article which also gets the same content. what is does it somehow moves the article in to that nav panel which is a preview of each post. I'll work with that

Comment: I found what was wrong. I hat to add strip_tags in that post preview panel, because it was taking some part of the post content string and remove some closing tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using e.g `echo "<img alt="text">";`try to escape the `"` such as `alt=\"text\"`